# Opening Web browser and mail app by clicking link in Firmonkey multi device project

Tags: android, ios, delphi, hyperlink, firemonkey

I'm working with Delphi 10 Seattle and Delphi XE8 and i've created an app which has a clickable link which opens the webbrowser on android, but since iOS 9 it doesn't work for iOS anymore. I have used the following code in this link: [Sending a url to another app](http://delphi.org/2013/10/sending-a-url-to-another-app-on-android-and-ios-with-delphi-xe5/). Does anyone have a fix for iOS 9?

Also is it possible to do the same with an email? By clicking on a label with the email opening your default mail app to send a mail to that address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to open mail app in Android need to add "mailto:" in front of the url and change code to:

```
Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW,
    TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString(URL)));
```

And for iOS I missed a piece of code from the link.